# proof rationals are dense, need help understanding

Tags: real-analysis

I need help understaning this proof:

[image]

Can someone see where they get the inequality I have marked in red from? I understand the (b-a) and 1/n, but not the other two.

Answer (score 1):

$j$ is the smallest element of $A$ so 
$$nb \leq j$$ now $m=j-1$ by definition so the inequality should be clear.

Comment: Offcourse, thanks!

Comment: "Offcourse" I know its a typo but it is a very Joycean pun.